Errors with linking with libjpeg-turbo
I've been trying to setup libjpeg for a project I'm working on, but after installing it I can't seem to get it to work.
I installed libjpeg-turbo from the github repo and installed cmake etc as it says in the building.md file and built it all. I have this all stored in its own directory
I then have some code for my project, nothing substantial yet but I just want to be able to turn a JPEG image into its raw pixel data which I followed a tutorial for, however when I'm trying to compile my code its not recognizing any of the functions defined in libjpeg
My file structure is Project -> Libraries, Code Libraries -> where I downloaded and built libjpeg-turbo Code -> several c files for my project
My c files are Image.c, ImageConversions.c, main.c
Image.c is just a class for storing data about an image
Image conversions is the bulk of the code, it has
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <jpeglib.h>
#include <jerror.c>
#include "Image.c"

then main.c just tries to pass the argument given in the cmd
when its run to my function for turning the JPEG to pixel data in
ImageConversions.c
it also has #include "ImageConversions.c" of course
the problem arises when I try to compile main.c, it doesn't
recognize any of the libjpeg functions as defined in
ImageConversions.c, e.g
Temp\ccy8qOzo.o:main.c:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateDecompress'

there is one of these for each time I reference a function from libjpeg
the command I'm running when I compile is gcc main.c -I "Path to Libraries folder" -I "Path to src folder within libjpeg-turbo"
These are the two directories which contain the libraries (one is within the other). I have also tried with -L flags instead, I've tried directly placing the .h files into the /MinGW/include folder and tried gcc main.c and the same happens
I have also tried the latter with the -ljpeg flag which I saw as a potential fix online but I got a error as -ljpeg was unrecognized. I feel this may be a clue to the problem but I'm not entirely sure
I tried to find a .a library file but I couldn't find one in libjpeg-turbo
This is my first time trying to install an external library and use it in c so I may have messed several things up with the installation or putting files in the wrong place, I tried to find a clear guide for this but couldn't find one
I'm using VScode if that makes any differences
I summarized the steps I took for installing it all at the start and if any other information is needed please ask
any help would be appreciated, Thankyou!

I haven't used those libraries, but it's almost never required to #include anything but a header.  You'll need to build the library first, or find a pre-built version somewhere to download.

Virtually every Linux distribution provides a pre-built package for libjpeg-turbo which provides the share-object or static library to link against. If yours doesn't, then Building libjpeg-turbo is for you. Make sure you have the dependencies installed, and just follow the procedure - just like you follow a recipe to bake a cake. If on Windows, I'm certain Msys2 provides a pre-built libjpeg-turbo package for MinGW.

You don't use -L instead of -l. You generally use both. -L tells the linker where the directory is which contains the archive files and -l tells the linker which particular archive filename you mean within that directory.
